# Python reading byte string that was saved as string

Tags: python, mysql, string, character-encoding

I have the following string that I read from a DB:

```
html_page = """b'<html lang="en"><body> Accompagnement g\xc3\xa9n\xc3\xa9ral Droit des Affaires :&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt;D\xc3\xa9velopper la connaissance des activit\xc3\xa9s techniques et commerciales d\xe2\x80\x99InterCloud, l\xe2\x80\x99identification et la ma\xc3\xaetrise des risques juridiques inh\xc3\xa9rents&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Assurer une veille sur les sujets qui peuvent toucher les interlocuteurs internes (droit des contrats, droit international, Droit du num\xc3\xa9rique, Donn\xc3\xa9es personnelles, Cloud Act, Data Act, Droit de la concurrence, Anti-corruption\xe2\x80\xa6)&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;Fournir des notes d\xe2\x80\x99information, recommandations ou documentation juridiques afin de mettre en conformit\xc3\xa9 l\xe2\x80\x99entreprise ou permettre d\xe2\x80\x99anticiper les \xc3\xa9volutions r\xc3\xa8glementaires.&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;</body></html>'"""
```

And this is how I read it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(uncompress(html_page) USING utf8) FROM TableX
```

The `html_page` column type in the DB is `longblob`.

It seems that the HTML string was inserted into the DB as a byte string, and when I read it, I get it as a string but the byte characters. When I print the type of `html_page`, it shows `str` in python.

My question is, How can I convert it to string without the bytes characters so I can decode characters like `\xe2\x80\x99`?

I don't know if the solution can be through the SQL query or using Python. However, I tried both but nothing worked. I went through all the other similar questions here on Stackoverflow, and nothing helped.

Comment: You could use `ast.literal_eval(html_page)` to convert back to `bytes`. Or `ast.literal_eval(html_page).decode()` for a string. The problem was that it was saved to the database with `str(html_page_as_bytes)`, either explicitly or implicitly. You should find the source of the problem and fix that.

Comment: You can `eval` it but you should fix whatever is providing `bytes` Tom your DB where it expected a `str`

Comment: @Axe319 it didn't work, I got this error: "SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it doesn't work. I got the same error as in the line above.

Comment: Maybe that you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Try `html_page.encode( 'latin1').decode( 'utf-8')`

Comment: @JosefZ it didn't solve everything, there are still encoded chars!